# Umbraco create - 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied

Tags: umbraco, iis-8.5, umbraco4

Create content - 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Hi All,

After having moved a version 4 website over to a new server using IIS8.5 (app runs in .net 2.0 in classic mode)  we have encountered a problem that happens when a user tries to create a new bit of content, the popup window comes up but displays -

**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.**

I have added the network service permissions and IIS_IUSRS with full access but Im still getting the error

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anonymous authentication?  If so, make sure to check the authentication settings.  When you edit the anonymous authentication settings it may be using a different account from what the application pool identity is set to use.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, yes and on the 'Edit Anonymous Authentication Credentials' window it is set to 'Application pool identity' and not 'Specific User'..

Comment: Make sure that application pool identity has permissions.  Here's how to do it: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities